# Println with two conditions

Tags: java, string, methods, boolean, conditional-statements

I wrote this code that's supposed to print all possible strings (lenght 4) of combination `(a, b, c, d)` with two conditions:

1. `a` always has to follow `b`
2. `a` and `d` can't be in the same string

When I run the following code, it gives me "

```
aaaa
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

"... I'm not sure what I did wrong. Thanks for your help !

```
    static void printAllKLength(char[] set, int k) {
    int n = set.length;
    printAllKLengthRec(set,"", n, k);
}

static void printAllKLengthRec(char[] set, String prefix, int n, int k) {
    if (k == 0) {
        if (aFollowsB(prefix) && hasOnlyAOrD(prefix) == true) {
            System.out.println(prefix);
            return;

        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        String newPrefix = prefix + set[i];
        printAllKLengthRec(set, newPrefix, n, k - 1);
    }
}

//Method for "a" always have to follow "b"
public static boolean aFollowsB(String str) {
    return str.indexOf('a') > str.indexOf('b');
}

//Method for "we can't have a and d in the same string"
public static boolean hasOnlyAOrD(String str) {
    return str.indexOf('a') == -1 || str.indexOf('d') == -1;
}

//Main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] set1 = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
    int k = 4;
    printAllKLength(set1, k);
}}
```

Comment: Well, `aaaa` plus a `java.lang.StackOverflowError` isn't *nothing*, I think...

Comment: You are right, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your return outside of the loop. If `a` *doesn't* follow `b`, you will have infinite recursion.

Now, this fixes your stackOverflow error - but you might still have some logic issues depending on how you want to handle *multiple* occurrences of `a` following `b`, or how to handle `a` following `b` if there is no `b`.

```
static void printAllKLengthRec(char[] set, String prefix, int n, int k) {
    if (k == 0) {
        if (aFollowsB(prefix) && hasOnlyAOrD(prefix)) {
            System.out.println(prefix);
        }

        return; // ALWAYS return now
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        String newPrefix = prefix + set[i];
        printAllKLengthRec(set, newPrefix, n, k - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my final solution :) Thanks for the help !

```
   static void printAllKLength(char[] set, int k) {
        int n = set.length;
        printAllKLengthRec(set,"", n, k);
    }

static void printAllKLengthRec(char[] set, String prefix, int n, int k) {
    if (k == 0) {
        if (aSuitB(prefix) && soitAouD(prefix) == true) {
            System.out.println(prefix);


        }  return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        String newPrefix = prefix + set[i];
        printAllKLengthRec(set, newPrefix, n, k - 1);
    }
}

//Methode "a" doit toujours suivre "b"
public static boolean aSuitB(String s) {
      char[] set1 = s.toCharArray();

      for (int i = 0; i < set1.length; i++) {
        // Si B est le dernier char, A ne peut pas suivre.
        if (i == set1.length - 1) {
          if (set1[i] == 'b') { return false; }
        // Pour le reste, si on rencontre B, s’assurer que A suit.
        } else {
          if (set1[i] == 'b') {
            if (set1[i+1] != 'a') { return false; }
          }
        }
      }

      return true;
    }



//Methode pour « on ne peut avoir a et d dans le même string »
public static boolean soitAouD(String s) {
      char[] set1 = s.toCharArray();

      boolean hasA = false;
      boolean hasD = false;

      for (int i = 0; i < set1.length; i++) {
        if (set1[i] == 'a') {
          hasA = true;
        } else if (set1[i] == 'd') {
          hasD = true;
        }
      }

      if (hasA && hasD) {
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    }

//Main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] set1 = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
    int k = 4;
    printAllKLength(set1, k);
}}
```